# Unable to install adb driver

Tags: android, windows, usb, adb, driver

Whenever I try to install Google USB driver or koush's UniversalAdbDriver off github.

I get the message "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your drive. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems."

[image]

I did manage to install a ADB driver for this phone on my old PC, but its been so long that I don't remember how I did it.

The alcatel official website doesn't list this phone and doesn't seem to provide drivers either.

How can I get ADB to detect my phone which is a ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 5036A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason why it wasn't allowed was because those drivers were for AMD.

I found a guide/driver that is from intel that works:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way: control panel > Hardware and sound > Devices and printers > Find your devices name > Update your driver devices in that. it worked for me.